# "Flutter run" issues - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, android-emulator

when I run 'flutter run' I get this error message.
I am new to flutter, dart, and android studio. I don't really know how to solve this

````
$ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you notice graphics artifacts,
consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.3.
    Searched in the following locations:
      - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.3/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.3.pom
      - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.3/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.3.pom
    Required by:
        project :

* Try:
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  148.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 ```
````

It happens with my android emulator and also when I try using my mobile phone
What do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

version issue here you can solve by changing your emulator SDK version or run in a real device (after changing SDK version) and also you can change your minimum and target SDK version.

Comment: after changing the sdk version. I manually downloaded 

   "kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.32.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32)
and  
'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4.32/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.32.jar'.

and it worked. thanks